# 2020 Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Christianity’s [fourth moderator election](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Ken Graham] [image: curiousdannii]

They’ll be joining [the existing crew](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5943881407397888/0).

Comment: Thank you ShemSeger for running!

Answer (score 7):

Congrats guys and thanks for throwing your hat in to make it contested Shem!

Looking forward to having far, far less to do!

Comment: Thank you, Peter! I feel very humbled with the thought of being a moderator. God will be our support in all things.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Let's get to work!

Comment: Peter, thanks for holding the line when there were no reinforcements. Kind of like the Marines on Guadalcanal at Bloody Ridge.  (Yeah, the precious blood ref was deliberate)

Answer (score 4):

#### We can only win

Thank you both for offering your service to us all. 
We are not worthy.

Comment: Thank you for your support, Korvin!

Answer (score 3):

Excellent!!  Thanks for stepping into this role.

Comment: Thanks for your support.